# Most important characters extraction

Tags: python, string, ocr

I'm extracting the character via OCR from id card. I have 4 different image but all images for 1 person(me). There'are 4 different text extraction results. For example, name extraction

```
[' BEYHAN', ' S BEYHAN h of', ' 2EYHAN', ' B3YHAN U']
```

this kind of array is returning. So i want to extract BEYHAN but there is some missing parts.

I can do most common words in array and of course will return BEYHAN but this is just works for this case. I want to get information of  `'2EYHAN'` and  `'B3YHAN'`. This are not BEYHAN but it has some information (`2-EYHAN`) and (`B-3-YHAN`). So do you know is there any algorithm or methods to use this kind of results ?

Comment: problem is extarct the name of person correctly. There are 4 different results but which one is correct ? We don't know. But we can combine the different results and can undersant what name is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are specific numbers that represent letters. So put in `wordt` the word that you need to extract and in `wordn` put the represented number. The code below is trying to match the word letter by letter and check if it is matched the letter or the represented number. if the all later matches then they will print the whole word if not he will start from the beginning.
I just put the number as an example. 
Run the code https://onlinegdb.com/BJaknZFbE

```
words = ['BEYHAN', ' S BEYHAN h of', '2EYHAN', 'B3YHAN U']
wordt='BEYHAN';
wordn=["2","3","4","6","7","8"];
m=0
c=''
n=0
for word in words:
    c=''
    m=0
    n=0
    for letter in word: 

        if letter==wordt[n] or letter==wordn[n]:

            m=m+1
            c=c+letter;
        else :
            if  len(wordt)!=m:
               m=0
               n=n-1
               c=''
            else:
               print(c) ;
               c=''
               m=0
               n=0   
        if len(wordt)-1>n:  
            n=n+1
        else:
           n=0
    if len(wordt)==m:
       print(c) ;
       c=''
       m=0
       n=0
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation of what your code does, how it works, and what the variables represent?